# Fetch Searched Data/Metadata In Lucene

Tags: java, search, lucene

Hi I am java developer and learning Lucene. I have a java class that index a pdf(lucene_in_action_2nd_edition.pdf) file and a search class that search some text from index. `IndexSearcher` is giving `Document` which shows that string exists in index(lucene_in_action_2nd_edition.pdf) or not.

But now `I want to get searched data or metadata. i.e. I want to know that at which page string is matched, or few text around matched string, etc...` How to do that?

Here is my LuceneSearcher.java class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File indexDir = new File("D:\\index");

    String querystr = "Advantages of FastVectorHighlighter";
    Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_40, "contents",
            new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40)).parse(querystr);

    int hitsPerPage = 100;
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(indexDir));
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(
            hitsPerPage, true);
    searcher.search(q, collector);
    ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;

    System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");
    for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {
        int docId = hits[i].doc;
        Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
        System.out.println((i + 1) + "... " + d.get("filename"));
        System.out.println("=====================================================");
        System.out.println(d.get("contents"));


    }

    // reader can only be closed when there
    // is no need to access the documents any more.
    reader.close();
}
```

Here `d.get("contents")` give full text(`generated by Tika`) of .pdf file, that was stored at time of indexing.

I want some information about searched text, so that I can show that on my web page or highlight searched text properly(like google search output). How to achieve that? Do we need to write some logic or Lucene does it internally?

Any type of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [org.apache.lucene.search.highlight](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/package-summary.html) package provides this functionality.

Such as:

```
SimpleHTMLFormatter htmlFormatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter();
Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(htmlFormatter, new QueryScorer(query));
for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {
    int docId = hits[i].doc;
    Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
    String text = doc.get("contents");
    String bestFrag = highlighter.getBestFragment(analyzer, "contents", text);
    //output, however you like.
```

You can also get a list of best Fragments from the highlighter, instead of just a single one, if you prefer, see the [`Highlighter` API](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have also applied Highlighter. But when complete book(100000 chars) are sent in 'text' then it is very difficult to look highlighted text from 500 pages... I want to send few text to highlighter so that term can be highlighted properly and used directly.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the problem with Highlighter you have described.  Highlighter should give you only fragments of the entire text (unless set to do otherwise), so why would you need to look over 500 pages?  If you don't want to pick matching fragments out of the content, then what do you want to do?